# Curve fitting through cloud of daily values using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, regression

I want to plot laboratory values (SCr_v) over time and find the best fitting regression curves (see plot 1 and 2). I don't want to restrict myself to a specific model if possible. Is there a function in python which I can use to solve my problem? Or any good article that would help? I'd like to solve my problem in Python.[image: Plot 1: laboratory values (SCr_v) over time]

[image: Plot 2: laboratory values (SCr_v) over time]

Comment: There are a bunch of options. Start with sklearn (general package) e.g. linear regression (standard model) https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Comment: Thanks @Peter. I don't want to restrict myself to a specific model. I uploaded a second plot where you can see that a linear curve is not the best fit. How would you approach that problem?

Comment: There are a lot of possible approaches. However, I would look for Generalized Additive Models (GAM). https://github.com/Bixi81/R-ml/blob/master/GAM_regression_splines.R or Python: https://pygam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Have a look at Ch. 7 in ISL https://github.com/tpn/pdfs/blob/master/An%20Introduction%20To%20Statistical%20Learning%20with%20Applications%20in%20R%20(ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing).pdf

Comment: Thank you @Peter, seems very interesting! I will have a look at it.